# DTO Optional during the PATCH call

Tags: nestjs, dto

I have a DTO to validate data coming from the `POST` request to create my Entity.

I want to have the "same" DTO to update my Entity during `PATCH` request, but some fields need to be Optional.

I tried to use Partial, but in that Way I miss some important control.
I can't use `@ValidateIf` because I don't have a property to detect if is it a `POST` or `PATCH`.

I can't use Extends, because I need to override every properties with `@IsOptional`

Is it possible to use "`createDTO`" to and update the entity, without *duplicate* the it and rename to "`updateDTO`" only for add `@IsOptional` property?

Answer (score 3):

I think you can accomplish this in two ways:

- Implement a custom interceptor/decorator that inject the http method in the body with a special key, then use `ValidateIf` with that injected property, like.

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpMethodInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(
    context: ExecutionContext,
    next: CallHandler
  ): Observable<any> {
    const req = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    req.body.httpMethod = req.method;

    return next.handle();
  }
}
```

```
export class TestDto {

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  public property: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  @ValidateIf(o => o.httpMethod === 'POST')
  public otherProperty: string;

  @IsString()
  public httpMethod: string;
}
```

- Use class validators `groups` passing the method as a value for each function, and pass the expected value on the decorators, something like:

```
  @Post()
  @UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({ groups: ['post'] }))
  public create(@Body() body: TestDto): Promise<any> {
    return;
  }

  @Patch()
  @UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({ groups: ['patch'] }))
  public update(@Body() body: TestDto): Promise<any> {
    return;
  }
```

```
export class TestDto {

  @IsNumberString(null, { groups: ['post'] }) //This validation will only apply if group has post in it, so on patch it will do nothing
  public test: string;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I saw Group, but I need apply it for each @Conditions (If I don't mistake, between 'post' and 'create'. Interceptor is not a bad solution but in that way I avoid the validation if httpMethod is popolated. I mean if `ValidateIf` is on username, and during the update I will fill the username field, all validators are "off" if I not mistake.

Comment: Sorry I didnt understand :/. What do you mean by filling the username?. Like inside the function after the dto validation? Or inside a decorator?